# MySQL format in database up to two decimal places, other times whole number

Tags: mysql

I have a field in a MySQL database that is currently set to 'double'

Sometimes, I will have whole numbers in this column, other times, I will have up to two decimal places. Problem is, sometimes I'm seeing numbers get entered in that happen to have 10 decimal places.

If I change the schema to decimal(4,2), that would be fine for numbers like 12.34 and that would also properly handle numbers like 29.3938759588 which would get truncated down to 29.39. I have no control over the data that is going in, so I can NOT change the data at the source. I just need to properly handle it at the insert level.

However, if I have a whole number, and i change the format of the column to decimal(4,2) it will get .00 added onto it which I don't want. I want whole numbers to show as integers, and decimals to show as decimals received, and if they happen to have more than 2 digit decimal places, truncate down to two.

Essentially how do i format the schema properly for this?

In Summary, potential input data:

```
23
83.0404850354
47.5
68.40
```

and I want the data to show in the column as:

```
23
83.04
47.5
68.40
```

Comment: Use: ROUND(number, decimal_places)

Comment: I would leave the current schema/table(s) and application code as it is.. And use a View for displaying with type checking if you need to round or not.. Using a View would save yourself the trouble you described and also saves time implementing.

Comment: using round(number,decimal_places) is for the view and selects only. I want to get the correct data being inserted to the table the first time.

Comment: Then go for varchar data type, that won't change anything

Comment: Why do you want to keep the zero in `68.40` but not in `47.5`?

Comment: 68.40 was a bad example. If it was 68.45 I want that to show as 68.45. 47.5 should show as 47.5 and not 47.50.